# What would a "Down Under" citizen be called?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, demonyms

Today is the 26th of January, it is Australia Day.

My question is about its nickname *Down Under* and derivatives.

Q. **If you had to, what would you call the citizen of a country called “Down Under”?**

What came to my mind were the following:

- Downunderer (Down Underer)
- Downunderian (Down Underian)

but I can't say which would sound more natural to a native English speaker.

(for non-Australians)

Q. How likely are you to use "Down Under" in your everyday speech? Would saying it mean you're joking, or just not serious, or maybe mocking the country?

Comment: You'd call him an "Aussie".

Comment: (What do you call a citizen of the United States?)

Comment: The proper 'alternate' suffix gives 'Downwegian'.

Comment: I think requests for neologisms or naming advice are ill-suited to the StackExchange Q&A format, as the "right" answer largely comes down to a matter of opinion. You might try chat, however.

Comment: @Mitch I like how it looks. Could you comment on the way it was formed, please?

Comment: @HotLicks I've heard the French use the word, Étatsunien, formed from the United States.

Comment: @Pablo it's a jocular suggestion based on a nonworking analogy with Glasgow->Glaswegian, Tasmania->Taswegian

Comment: A member of the downunderclass?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to coin and adjective from the expression "Down Under" ***[-ian](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ian?s=t)*** is probably the more common suffix you would use in this case:

> - a suffix with the same meaning and properties as -an; -ian, is now the more productive of the two suffixes in recent coinages, ***especially when the base noun ends in a consonant***: *Orwellian; Washingtonian*.

(Dictionary.com)

[Downunderian](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22downunderian%22) is not a common term but there are a few usages availabbe on the net. See for instance the site:

> - [downunderian.com](https://who.is/whois/downunderian.com)

Comment: A large number of the search results are false hits returning 'down under Ian'

Comment: @Spagirl - yes, it is not a common term, but that is the suffix that you would probably use if you want to coin an adjective from Downunder.

Comment: Note: a _downuderian_ may well be quite a different beast from a _Downunderian_. I’m not sure what exactly, but unless Down Under has some rather unusual laws on dress code, the two are unlikely to consistently coincide.

Comment: I was making a joke on the typo, which entailed the former being a ‘dow-**nuder**-ian’.